# Don't display media on the Desktop

Tags: 11.04, launcher, usb-drive, dvd

How can I get media icons to not display on the desktop? I do not want them there because they already show in the launcher on the left and there is no point in having them both places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1** - Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

**2** - Search for **gconf-editor**

**3** - Once opened click on **Apps** > **Nautilus** > **Desktop**

**4** - Untick **Volumes Visible**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this guide:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/hide-removable-drive-icons-from-your-ubuntu-desktop/

Comment: Just so you know in the future, it is better not to have out-link-only answers because content might be deleted or moved if the other website goes down or gets re-worked. If the relevant content is copied in, it can be improved. And of course you don't have to do it right away, you can used the edit link.

Comment: Thank you for finding the guide, nickguletskii. But, as George said, it is highly encouraged to give a nice answer with more detailed information :)